# Не знаю как исправить ошибки TASM/Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Написал программу, выдает ошибки. Не знаю как их исправить, и вроде как из-за одной остальные и появились.Помогите пожалуйста их исправить, и если нужно я могу более подробно прокомментировать.

Задача:
Двуйбайтный код вводится с клавиатуры в двоичном виде. Показать на экране его числовое значение в hex виде.

Мой код

```
.386
dseg segment use16
text1 db 13,10,'Type BIN: $'
text2 db 13,10,0Dh,0Ah,'Result..: ',0Dh,0Ah,'$'
Buf db 17,18 dup(?)
dseg ends

cseg segment use16
assume cs:cseg, ds:dseg

m1:
mov cx,dseg


mov ah,9    
lea DX,text1
int 21h
mov ah,0Ah
lea DX,Buf
int 21h
mov DX,DS:Buf
lea Di,DS:Buf+2
mov CX,DS:Buf+1
m2:
cmp DS:[DI],31h
jne short m3 ;если не равно
or AX, 00000001b
m3:
shl AX,1
inc DI
loop m2
mov ah,9
lea DX,text2
int 21h
mov DX,AX
call PECHAT
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

;Печатает символ и переводит курсор на позицию вправо
WRITE proc 
  mov AH,9
  xor BH,BH
  mov BL,07H
  ;mov CX,1
  mov AL,DL
  int 10h
  inc DL
  ret
WRITE endp

;Печатает одну шестнадцатеричную цифру (младшую тетраду DL)
;(старшая тетрада должна быть равна 0)
;DL - цифра
;--------------------------------------------------------
NA_CONSOL proc
    cmp  DL,0Ah 
    jae  BUKVA
    add  DL,30h
    JMP  POKAZ
BUKVA:
    add  DL,37h
POKAZ:
  call WRITE     
  ret
NA_CONSOL endp

;Печатает две шестнадцатеричные цифры
RASHIREN proc
  mov  DH,DL
  mov  CL,4
  shr  DL,CL
  call NA_CONSOL
  mov  DL,DH
  and  DL,0Fh
  call NA_CONSOL
  ret
RASHIREN endp

PECHAT proc ;двухбайтное число на консоль
    mov CX,DX
    call RASHIREN
    xchg DL,CH
    call RASHIREN
    ret
PECHAT endp

cseg ends
end m1
```

Ошибки выдает такие:

1. operand types do not match - `mov DX,DS:Buf`
2. operand types do not match - `mov CX,DS:Buf+1`
3. argument needs type override - `cmp DS:[DI],31h`

Comment: Ошибки мы получим через pipe из libastral? Выкладывайте их сюда!

Comment: @gbg Вот, я написал.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо доброму человеку, программа работает.Всё.

```
.386

dseg segment use16
text1 db 13,10,'Type BIN: $'
text2 db 13,10,'Result..: $'
Buf   db 17,0,17 dup(?)
dseg ends

sseg segment stack use16
db 256 dup(?)
sseg ends

cseg segment use16
assume cs:cseg,ds:dseg,ss:sseg
m1:
mov cx,dseg
mov ds,cx

mov ah,09h
lea dx,text1
int 21h

mov ah,0Ah
lea dx,Buf
int 21h

lea di,ds:[Buf+2]
xor ch,ch
mov cl,byte ptr ds:[Buf+1]
xor ax,ax
m2:
shl ax,1
cmp byte ptr ds:[di],31h
jne short m3
or ax,00000001b
m3:
inc di
loop m2
push ax
mov ah,09h
lea dx,text2
int 21h
pop dx
call pechat
mov ah,4Ch
mov al,00h
int 21h

write proc
mov ah,02h
int 21h
ret
write endp

na_consol proc
cmp dl,0Ah
jae bukva
add dl,30h
jmp pokaz
bukva:
add dl,37h
pokaz:
call write
ret
na_consol endp

rashiren proc
mov dh,dl
mov cl,4
shr dl,cl
call na_consol
mov dl,dh
and dl,0Fh
call na_consol
ret
rashiren endp

pechat proc
push dx
xchg dh,dl
call rashiren
pop dx
call rashiren
ret
pechat endp

cseg ends
end m1
```